# What is the "Install this third-party software" box in the installer and what third-party software is installed?

Tags: software-installation, ubiquity

When installing Ubuntu it always has this box which says `Install this third-party software`, but I am wondering exactly which third-party software and where it is installing it from.

I can see the description below, however I want to know exactly which software is being installed, which packages, and from where.

> Ubuntu GNOME uses third-party software to play Flash, MP3 and other media, and to work with some graphics and wi-fi hardware. Some of this software is proprietary. The software is subject to license terms included with its documentation.

[image: Install this third-party software check box]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Edit**

After digging some more through output of

`dpkg --get-selections | xargs apt-cache policy | grep -B5 'multiverse'` it turns out there exists meta-package `ubuntu-restricted-addons`. The `/var/lib/dpkg/info/ubuntu-restricted-addons.list` pointed me to the file `/usr/share/doc/ubuntu-restricted-addons/README.Debian`

The contents of that file state:

> This package was split into ubuntu-restricted-extras and
>   ubuntu-restricted-addons to allow the desktop CD installer (ubiquity)
>   to install a subset of the packages available in the original
>   ubuntu-restricted-extras package.
>
> Moving forward, ubuntu-restricted-extras should only contain
>   multiverse packages, whereas ubuntu-restricted-addons should contain
>   main and universe packages, as well as any packages from multiverse
>   that have been vetted by a lawyer.
>
> Since ubuntu-restricted-extras depends on ubuntu-restricted-addons,
>   users should be discouraged from installing ubuntu-restricted-addons
>   outside of the desktop CD installer.  This is the reasoning behind the
>   warning and sparse description in ubuntu-restricted-addons.
>
> -- Evan Dandrea  Thu, 05 Aug 2010 16:14:43 -0400

Thus, Ubuntu installer allows you to install `ubuntu-restricted-addons` meta-package.

`apt-cache` tells us what goes into that package:

```
xieerqi:
$ apt-cache depends ubuntu-restricted-addons                                                                            
ubuntu-restricted-addons
  Recommends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly
  Recommends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly
  Recommends: flashplugin-installer
    flashplugin-installer:i386
  Recommends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad
  Recommends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
  Recommends: gstreamer1.0-libav
  Recommends: gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3
  Recommends: gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3
  Recommends: chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
  Recommends: oxideqt-codecs-extra
  Conflicts: ubuntu-restricted-addons:i386
```

This is pretty much the same output as on my 15.10 virtual machine.

Thus , my conclusion is that `ubuntu-restricted-addons` from `multiverse` repository is where the third-party software comes from.

**Original post**
In terms of `/etc/apt/sources.list` file those would be any software that comes from `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $RELEASE multiverse` as well as `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $RELEASE restricted` repository.

It's also references in the `software-properties-gtk` program

[image]

You can list packages in those repositories with

```
awk '/^Package/' /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_$(lsb_release -c | awk '{print $2}' )_multiverse_binary-$(dpkg --print-architecture)_Packages
```

and

```
awk '/^Package/' /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_$(lsb_release -c | awk '{print $2}' )_restricted_binary-$(dpkg --print-architecture)_Packages
```

Comment: So which exact software is installed? Can you give me a list of packages which it installs because I can't believe that it installs all the software in the `multiverse` and `restricted` repositories?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda the list of packages of all the available packages is very large. Use the `awk` one-liners I've posted. Alternatively you could use those oneliner in a fresh install and pass on the output to `apt-cache policy` through pipe and `xargs`

Comment: Off the top of my head such packages as drivers for `broadcom` and `nvidia` hardware are 100% proprietary. Microsoft compatible fonts, kde-related packages fall into "free,but restricted by license" category

Comment: So is there no comprehensive list somewhere of all the things this will install?

Comment: Nowadays it also installs graphics drivers if checked, so it's not limited by `ubuntu-restricted-addons` only.

Answer (score 4):

What it installs is [ubuntu-restricted-extras](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ubuntu-restricted-extras/) for playback of media that is not encrypted but using a proprietary codec (mainly mp3, mp4).

It is part of the Fluendo package. Fluendo is a [Canonical partner](http://www.fluendo.com/partners/) so their own software is in the partner repository.  [gstreamer0.10-fluendo-plugins](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gstreamer0.10-fluendo-plugins/) is the name of it and it has all of their playback codecs but has a price of $34.95

Comment: I beg to differ.  Restricted extras package has to be manually installed. I've installed my Ubuntu 14.04 with `Install third party software` box checked, and yet `apt-cache policy ubuntu-restricted-extras` tells me `Installed: (none)`

Answer (score 3):

The message "...uses third-party software to play Flash, MP3 and other media..." is in a package named ubiquity and it is `Template: ubiquity/text/prepare_foss_disclaimer`.

`Template: ubiquity/text/prepare_nonfree_software` is the label of the checkbox which contains the text "Install this third-party software"

In the file `ubiquity/plugins/ubi-prepare.py` there is a `def ok_handler(self)` that checks if that checkbox was clicked on into the active state and sets a varible `use_nonfree` to true if it was.  If `use_nonfree` is true it causes `universe` and `multiverse` to be preseeded and if it hasn't already done so it causes `ubuntu-restricted-addons` (or `kubuntu-restricted-addons` if it's KDE) to be preseeded.

It does nothing with `ubuntu-restricted-extras`, only `ubuntu-restricted-addons`.  There is even a changelog entry explaining this is true.

`./ubiquity-2.18.8.11/debian/changelog:  * Install kubuntu-restricted-addons, not kubuntu-restricted-extras`

Comment: Actually it does have something to do with restricted-extras. Refer to the edit on my answer

Comment: Please show me the code.

Comment: No code. Read the file `/usr/share/doc/ubuntu-restricted-addons/README.Debian` I posted contents of that file in my answer

Comment: It says ubuntu-restricted-extras depends on ubuntu-restricted-addons not the other way around.  The OP asked about the installer.

Comment: Yes, depends means without `addons` you cannot have `extras`.  Once you boot freshly installed systems, you don't have `restricted-extras` , only `restricted-addons`.  Addons come with the installer

Comment: Use `apt-get source ubiquity` in an empty folder then `grep -r 'restricted-extras' .` on the source. Either that or install 15.04 in a VM and see what happens.

Comment: Take a look at the screenshot from my Ubuntu 15.10 VM. Why does `apt-cache policy` say `Installed: (none)` ? http://imgur.com/uI8ojN4

Comment: What I am trying to say is `restricted-addons` is subset of `restricted-extras`. They're related. But extras has to be manually installed

Comment: I ran out of time. I'll get back to you. You are fun!